# Restangular interceptor to handle $q.all request

Tags: angularjs, interceptor, restangular, angular-http-interceptors

I need help for Restangular interceptor. i can retry request all of the failed API calls but the data was not returned to the success method of the calling function.

When not using `$q.all`, the interceptor was working fine. I need help how can I return the data.

**Below is my code for the interceptor:**

```
authrestangular.factory("AuthRestangular", function (Restangular, $q, $injector, $location, localStorageService, $filter, $timeout, cfpLoadingBar, $cookies) {
    return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
        RestangularConfigurer.addFullRequestInterceptor(function (element, operation, route, url, headers) {
            cfpLoadingBar.start();
            var token = $cookies.get('token');
            if (token) {
                headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + token;
            }
        });

        RestangularConfigurer.setErrorInterceptor(function (response, deferred, responseHandler) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                var prevConfig = response.config;
                _responseError($q, $injector, $location, response, prevConfig).then(function (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                    if (pendingRequests.length > 0) {
                        angular.forEach(pendingRequests, function (req) {
                            req.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + res.access_token;
                            _retryHttpRequest(res, req, deferred);
                        });
                        pendingRequests = [];
                    } else {
                        _retryHttpRequest(res, response.config, deferred)
                    }
                    var authService = $injector.get("authService");
                    authService.authentication.isRefreshing = false;
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log("Error", err);
                });
                return false;
            }

            if (response.status === 500) {
                $location.path("error");
            }

            return true;
        });

        RestangularConfigurer.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
            var extractedData;

            if (operation === "getList") {
                extractedData = response.data.Rows;
                extractedData.pagination = response.data.Pagination;
            } else {
                extractedData = response.data;
            }

            return extractedData;
        });

    });
});

var _responseError = function ($q, $injector, $location, response, prevConfig) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var authService = $injector.get("authService");
    if (authService.authentication.isRefreshing) {
        pendingRequests.push(prevConfig);
    } else {
        authService.refreshToken().then(function (response) {
            if (pendingRequests.length > 0) {
                angular.forEach(pendingRequests, function (req) {
                    req.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + response.access_token;
                    _retryHttpRequest($injector, req, deferred)
                });
            } else {
                prevConfig.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + response.access_token;
                _retryHttpRequest($injector, prevConfig, deferred);
            }
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }, function () {
            authService.logOut();
            $location.path("/portal");
            deferred.reject(response);
        });
    }
    authService.authentication.isRefreshing = true;
    return deferred.promise;
}

var _retryHttpRequest = function ($injector, config, deferred) {
    $http = $http || $injector.get("$http");
    $http(config).then(function (response) {
        var extractedData;

        if (response.data.Rows && response.data.Pagination) {
            extractedData = response.data.Rows;
            extractedData.pagination = response.data.Pagination;
        }
        else {
            extractedData = response.data;
        }

        deferred.resolve(extractedData);
    }, function (response) {
        deferred.reject(response);
    });
}
```

Included above are all my codes for my interceptor, the refreshToken() is just refreshing my token. What I did here is if the refreshToken() function is called once then I set a flag that my token is still refreshing. This will fix the issue on the token when it is refreshed and the other API calls is still using the old access token.

**Below is the function that calls the api**

```
var initializeDDLs = function () {
    var ddlAPIcalls = [
        authRestangular.one("PositionAPI/getddl").get(),
        authRestangular.one("Employee201API/getddl").get(),
        authRestangular.one("StatusAPI/getddl").get({ moduleId: Common.constants.civilStatus }),
        authRestangular.one("TypeAPI/getddl").get({ moduleId: Common.constants.bloodType }),
        authRestangular.one("PositionAPI/getPositionCodeddl").get(),
        authRestangular.one("TypeAPI/getddl").get({ moduleId: Common.constants.educationalLevel }),
        authRestangular.one("EmployerAPI/getddl").get(),
        authRestangular.one("BusinessUnitAPI/getddl").get(),
        authRestangular.one("TypeAPI/getddl").get({ moduleId: Common.constants.locationType }),
        authRestangular.one("StatusAPI/getddl").get({ moduleId: Common.constants.employmentStatus }),
        authRestangular.one("StatusAPI/getddl").get({ moduleId: Common.constants.employmentStatusBefore }),
        authRestangular.one("TypeAPI/getddl").get({ moduleId: Common.constants.salaryType }),
        authRestangular.one("TypeAPI/getddl").get({ moduleId: Common.constants.basicRateType }),
        authRestangular.one("TypeAPI/getddl").get({ moduleId: Common.constants.documentType }),
        authRestangular.one("Employee201API/getsystemroleddl").get(),
        authRestangular.one("ShiftAPI/getddl").get(),
        authRestangular.one("KeyQuestionAPI/getddl").get()
    ];

    $q.all(ddlAPIcalls)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(response);
        });

};
```

The code won't trigger the `.then` response which is the success response suppose to be will return the data that im going to display.

Please help. dont know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the condition before pushing an API to list.
Example:

```
var apiList = [];

if (!$rootScope.apiOneData) {
  apiList.push(ApiOne.then(
    function (data) {
      // Success this API
      $rootScope.apiOneData = data;
    },
    function (error) {
      // Handle error in this API
    }
  ));
}

if (!$rootScope.apiTwoData) {
  apiList.push(ApiTwo.then(function (data) {
    // Success this API
    $rootScope.apiOneData = data;
  }));
}

if (!apiList.length) {
  return;
}

$rootScope.isLoading = true;

return $q.all(apiList)
  .then(function (data) {

    // Success all
    // Do something
  }, function (error) {
    // Error
    // Do something
  });
```

Comment: what do you mean check the condition? sorry. im not familiar with rootScope